# Laravel artisan always thinks its in local

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I set several ENV variables with Laravel Forge which are correctly picked up by the application. However artisan doesn't seem to pick up my environment. `php artisan env` returns:

```
Current application environment: local
```

In the nginx configuration I also have

```
fastcgi_param ENV "test";
```

This is how I detect my environment:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {
    return getenv('ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

How can I have artisan think its in the test environment?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your laravel forge site and click on 'Edit Deploy Script'.

Change line 4 to

```
php artisan migrate --env=production
```

or whatever env you need.

You will need to do the same when running an artisan command in the console.

```
php artisan <command> --env=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if your .env file is correctly configured. Take a look in your .env and set this:

```
APP_ENV=test
```

after that try to clear your configuration. Type this in your terminal:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and to finish verify your environment with this:

```
php artisan env
```

I hope this help you.

Regards!