# Laravel 5 environment is always 'Production' when it is infact 'Local'

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.1

I am trying to set up two environments: local and production.

So far, I have added a `bootstrap/environment.php` file which is:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('Ben'),
    'staging' => array('staging.domain.org'),
    'production' => array('domain.org'),
));
```

and two `.env` files - `.local.env` and `.production.env`with the different environment variables such as: `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true`.

My laptop's hostname is called `Ben`.

The problem I'm having is the `php artisan env` always returns `Production` and thus, I can't load my application.

Also, within the `production.env` file, if I change the `APP_DEBUG` variable to true or false, it doesn't make a difference on the web application - it always returns "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged your question as `laravel-5.1`, but your code doesn't work in 5.1. It would throw an error, since `detectEnvironment` [expects a closure](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cbf68c02542e3d668086283c1928347d1e6f605f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L470).

Comment: I followed this tutorial - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082173/laravel-5-environment-detection, before posting this, and it returns as `Call to a member function detectEnvironment() on null` error.

Answer (score 12):

I had that problem. I am using Laravel 5.2.14 with homestead. I fixed the problem adding this line:

`'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`

in the file: `config\app.php`

I upgraded my Laravel app from a previous version which did not contain that line or at least I did not have it. Latest file version in:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php

Comment: This seems to work. I'm still baffled as to where "production" was coming from before I added this line...?

Comment: Ran into this issue in laravel 5.4. It's due to the fact that i've upgraded from 5.1 to 5.4 directly from `composer update`, and missed this upgrade instruction on the laravel website.

Answer (score 2):

The `bootstrap/environment.php` file is not loaded in Laravel 5.1 anymore. Laravel does not load different `env` files depending on the environment.

Laravel now only loads a single `.env` file. This file should not be in your version control. For your production server, you'll simply put different values into the `.env` file.

---

For more information, read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#environment-configuration).

Comment: Yes, I initially read the docs, but for multiple environments like I'm trying to set up, it's not particularly detailed - specifically into how you can specify your `local` and `production` names.

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how to detect multiple environments please?

Comment: Again, there's no need to set up multiple environments. You just change the actual values in your `.env` file on every server.

Comment: But how can Laravel detect whether to use my local one because I'm on my laptop, or the production one because it's live?

Comment: Again, only use one single file. On your local machine that file will have the information you need for your local environment. On your production machine, that file will have the information you need for your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This bugged the hell out of me in Laravel 5. The way I fixed it was by adding the following to the end of bootstrap/app.php:

```
    $app->detectEnvironment(function () use($app) {
        $env = env('APP_ENV', 'local');
        $file = ".env.{$env}";
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($file);
    });
```

Then add files for each environment, e.g. .env.local, .env.production etc.

You can now swicth environment files by setting the APP_ENV environment variable. The code defaults to '.env.local' if APP_ENV is not set. Test this works with:

```
    $ APP_ENV=production ./artisan env
    Current application environment: production

    $ ./artisan env
    Current application environment: local
```

Laravel automatically sets APP_ENV to 'testing' when running phpunit (specifically in the Foundation/Testing/TestCase class), so make sure you have a '.env.testing' file if you want to use different database settings etc when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

**For Laravel >= 5.1**

It's because your environment is configured wrong or your .env file was not correctly set.
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50769403/9916285)

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Maybe that help you.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your .env file in laravel and set your

```
PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT=production

PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID={// Your production MID}

PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY={// Your production Merchant key}

PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE=DEFAULT

PAYTM_CHANNEL=WEB
```